# Ranking when there are duplicates

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I return the ranking of each value in a row, even in the case of duplicates? Please see my example below.

While many questions have been answered regarding the handling of duplicate values in a ranking, I have come short in achieving a method that works for all of my cases.

**EDIT:** The previous picture above was a bad example that did not address my problem. Here is a new picture of the behavior.

[image]

In certain cases it skips to 7 when the rank should only be 1:6. In other cases it seems to work, and then not work in similar cases. Data is:

```
2.61879723030607    2.3428  2.61879723030607    2.4571  2.7324  2.1790
2.97203355745108    2.5355  2.97203355745108    2.6721  3.0561  2.4136
2.4895  2.2781  2.6218  2.4369  2.6898  2.1361
2.32650000000000    2.2124  2.3453  2.32650000000000    2.3938  2.0283
2.34132608128450    2.1331  2.34132608128450    2.2800  2.5758  2.0446
2.58668483692925    2.1476  2.58668483692925    2.3019  2.5124  2.0135
2.2555  2.0884  2.3368  2.0980  2.3928  1.9787
2.32878217762168    2.1080  2.32878217762168    2.1250  2.5360  1.9807
2.50891263421977    2.2480  2.50891263421977    2.4239  2.9070  2.2638
2.97755287506272    2.4457  2.97755287506272    2.6830  3.0566  2.3987
3.0850  2.5380  5.3880  2.8304  3.1579  2.5030
3.0120  2.3815  3.0639  2.6762  3.0831  2.4253
2.49235468138485    2.1436  2.49235468138485    2.3159  2.5542  1.9991
2.13109025589563    2.1060  2.13109025589563    2.1555  2.3225  1.9787
2.24900295032614    2.0332  2.24900295032614    2.1780  2.5084  2.0043
2.4010  2.0438  2.5857  2.2126  2.4511  2.0329
```

**EDIT2:** Implementing RANK instead of RANK.EQ showing no difference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try `RANK` instead of `RANK.EQ` as below. Though I am not sure whether this will work as I am testing on Excel 07.

Enter the following formula in `Cell H1`

```
=RANK(A1,$A1:$F1,1)+COUNTIF($A1:A1,A1)-1
```

Copy/Drag the formula down and across (to right) as required. See image for reference.

[image]

As per Microsoft Documentation on `RANK.EQ function` [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/RANK-EQ-function-284858ce-8ef6-450e-b662-26245be04a40)

> RANK.EQ gives duplicate numbers the same rank. However, the presence of duplicate numbers affects the ranks of subsequent numbers. For example, in a list of integers sorted in ascending order, if the number 10 appears twice and has a rank of 5, then 11 would have a rank of 7 (no number would have a rank of 6)

Comment: @EvanFriedland - See my answer.

Comment: See my edit#2 picture, I have tested in 2010 and 2013

Answer (score 0):

I think you've got an error in your setup. My understanding is each row is meant to be a separate independent case, however your formula for calculating rank has fixed row and column references, when it should have only fixed column references. Right now, the rank for every value is being found based on the first row in your data. Instead of:

```
=RANK.EQ(B4,$B$4:$G$4,1)
```

It should be:

```
=RANK.EQ(B4,$B4:$G4,1)
```

This then alters your results in the 2nd and 3rd blocks and you should get the desired result in the 3rd block.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please see my edit as the second picture is now the only relevant one.

Comment: Your updated example shows your issue well, but unfortunately I can't reproduce. I have copied your data exactly but I'm getting your actual desired result. I'm guessing it is some kind of issue with calculations on numbers stored as floating points. It would be easier to debug if we can see which part of your formula is failing. Can you please apply the RANK.EQ and COUNTIF formulas in separate cells so we can see which is failing?

Comment: I will not be able to update until tomorrow. I think it's too moody if a problem for me to pinpoint... My workaround is adding a very small dynamic number to my ranges like "+ COL(A1)/1000000" to just eliminate ties. It means another table but it's my best bet if I can't get a formula to work. Will update tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

With the formula below in **Cell B2:B4** you can filter the unique numbers in **Column A**.
Please note that this is an **array formula** so once you enter it you have to mark it and press `CTRL` + `ALT` + `DEL`. Hope this solves your problem. More details regarding this formula you can also find here https://exceljet.net/formula/extract-unique-items-from-a-list

```
Column A     Column B
    1
    1         1 = {=INDEX($A$1:$A$5000,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$5000),0))}
    1         2 = {=INDEX($A$1:$A$5000,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B2,$A$1:$A$5000),0))}
    1         6 = {=INDEX($A$1:$A$5000,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B3,$A$1:$A$5000),0))}
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    2
    1
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
    6
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Michi. However, this seems to address the pulling of values from a list, rather than returning a rank for (in your example) each row. My example would be each column, but this still does not apply.